# Multiline Text output in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, output, multilinestring

I need to output 5-8 lines to my window. I managed that with a TextArea, BUT, i don't  want the user to be able to write inside it, AND I also can't use my keyboard to navigate between buttons and other elements on the page.

Lets say that there is a String named text, which field type do you think i should write it out into? Text is good but only lets me use a single line.

```
Text  actiontarget3;
String text = new String(" something  \n  Second line something");
actiontarget4.setText(text);
```

Because I use FXML to design the menu page, the relevant part is:

```
  <Text  fx:id="actiontarget3"
  GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
```

Basically, I managed to get the info from a ping test, added it to an `ArrayList<String>`
and I want to display the results on the Graphic User Interface. But the above example covers my problems without having to copy paste here the entire code.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977295/control-for-displaying-multiline-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it so a TextArea is not editable.

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
ta.setEditable(false);
```

You may also want to look into using a [JTextPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html#recap).

Comment: Thank you^^
I used the Label solution from the comment to my queastion, but thank you for the additional info, it will be useful =)