# How to add multiple lines in Label JavaFX

Tags: java, loops, text, javafx, uilabel

I have a problem that I don't really know how to add a multiple lines into Label in JavaFX.

For example:

```
 Label label = new Label();
 for(int i= 0; i<10; i++){
     label.setText(Integer.toString(i));
 }
```

So when the loop finishes, the label just only shows the final value which is 9.

So any solutions that can show all the numbers 1 - 9 with the break lines( such as '\n') between them.

This problem that happens when i want to show the Bill of my project that contain many dishes.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Control for displaying multiline text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977295/control-for-displaying-multiline-text)

Comment: Thank you but in my situation, the values when i put into the label are not available yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append and not set the text over and over again
**AND** you need the new line character **'\n'**

my suggestion would be like using a variable to append the information and when you are done with that step, then set the label.text

## Example:

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder():
Label label = new Label();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    msg.append(Integer.toString(i));
    msg.append(",\n");  //this is the new line you need
}
label.setText(msg.toString());
```